# How are recent tags on homepage queried?

Tags: discussion, tags, homepage, algorithm, recent-tags

Hi, I'd like to know what algorithm is used to display recent tags on homepage? How many recent questions tags is taken under consideration when displaying that tag cloud? Any details?